# sqlite3 fails to import db from sql file

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to install PolicyD v2, but when creating sqlite3 database from sql file it throw errors:

```
SQLite version 3.7.17 2013-05-20 00:56:22
sqlite> .read /usr/doc/policyd2-2.0.14/policyd2.sqlite
Error: near line 1: unrecognized token: "#"
Error: near line 43: no such table: policies
Error: near line 44: no such table: policies
Error: near line 45: no such table: policies
Error: near line 46: no such table: policies
Error: near line 47: no such table: policies
Error: near line 174: unrecognized token: "#"
Error: near line 215: unrecognized token: "#"
Error: near line 263: no such table: quotas
Error: near line 264: no such table: quotas
Error: near line 303: unrecognized token: "#"
Error: near line 447: no such table: amavis_rules
Error: near line 462: unrecognized token: "#"
Error: near line 570: unrecognized token: "#"
Error: near line 617: unrecognized token: "#"
```

And /usr/doc/policyd2-2.0.14/policyd2.sqlite looks like this:

```
line:1 # Core schema
line:2 # Copyright (C) 2009, AllWorldIT
line:3 # Copyright (C) 2008, LinuxRulz
...

/* Policies */
CREATE TABLE policies (
        ID                      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        Name                    VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        Priority                SMALLINT NOT NULL,
        Description             TEXT,
        Disabled                SMALLINT NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
 ) ;

...
line:43 INSERT INTO policies (Name,Priority,Description) VALUES ('Default',0,'Default System Policy');
line:44 INSERT INTO policies (Name,Priority,Description) VALUES ('Default Outbound',10,'Default Outbound System Policy');
line:45 INSERT INTO policies (Name,Priority,Description) VALUES ('Default Inbound',10,'Default Inbound System Policy');
line:46 INSERT INTO policies (Name,Priority,Description) VALUES ('Default Internal',20,'Default Internal System Policy');
line:47 INSERT INTO policies (Name,Priority,Description) VALUES ('Test',50,'Test policy');
```

Created tables:

```
sqlite> .tables
checkhelo_blacklist        policy_group_members     
checkhelo_tracking         policy_groups            
checkhelo_whitelist        policy_members           
greylisting_autoblacklist  quotas_limits            
greylisting_autowhitelist  quotas_tracking          
greylisting_tracking       session_tracking         
greylisting_whitelist
```

I can create 'policies', 'quotas', 'amavis_rules' tables by hand.

**So whats wrong here?** Other tables were created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is caused by console and some malformed (encoding/decoding) characters in file like tab,space,new line.

Solution for this is using grep.

```
grep -v "#" sql.file | sqlite3 sqlite3.db
```